# Issues while creating a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, json, pageblocktable

I have made an external API call (JSON type). And I have stored the fields and values in a Map<String, List> object.

Now I have to created a visual force page that displays the Map in columnwise format.

Please refer to the below code:

```
public with sharing class testClass{    
    
    // Initialization
    public string companyName{get; set;}

    public void showRecord(){
        Map<String, List<Object>> pageToWordMap = new Map<String, List<Object>>();
        
        // Input from the user
        String str =  companyName; // input from Visual force page
        String query = '';
        
        //create a rest endpoint
        string requestEndPoint = '***** end point *******' ;
        
        // requests        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(requestEndPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('ApiToken', '*********************');   
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');  
      
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

         if (response.getStatusCode() == 200 && response.getBody() != null){
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            List <Object> data = (List<Object>)results.get('Data'); 
                         
             
            // for loop
            
            for(Object dta : data){
                // getting the attributes of data
                Map<String, Object> attributes = (Map<String, Object>) dta;
                // now loop through the data
                for(String lst : attributes.keyset()){
                    // handle response
                    String indexKey = lst;
                    
                    if(!pageToWordMap.containsKey(indexKey)){
                        // add the key and new list
                        pageToWordMap.put(indexKey, new List<Object>());
                    }
                    // get the key and add the value
                    pageToWordMap.get(indexKey).add(attributes.get(indexKey));
                } 
                
                // for debug purpose
                /*
                for(String curPage: pageToWordMap.keySet())
                {
                    String key = curPage;
                    String val = (String)pageToWordMap.get(curPage);
                    System.debug(key+'-----'+val);
                } */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Visualforce code, that I am trying is:

> 

```
<apex:page controller="testClass" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"> 
> 
>       <apex:form>
>             <apex:pageBlock title="Company Search">
>                 <apex:pageBlocksection >
>                     Please enter the company name <apex:inputText value = "{! companyName}"/>
>                     <apex:commandButton action="{! showRecord}" value="submit"/>
>                 </apex:pageBlocksection>             
>             </apex:pageBlock>
>             <apex:pageBlock title="The Data">
>                 <apex:pageBlockTable value = "{! pageToWordMap}" var = "json">
>                   <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{! json.NAME}"/>
>                 </apex:pageBlockTable>
>             </apex:pageBlock> 
>         </apex:form> </apex:page>
```

I am new to APEX programming, and now I am not able to figure out how to create the record columns.

The error is ***

> Unknown property 'testClass.pageToWordMap'

---

The column header names are:

1. NAME
2. BVDID
3. COUNTRY_ISO_CODE

please help?????

Answer (score 0):

`pageToWordMap` is a local variable to `showRecord()`. You want to make it a property of your Apex class instead, so that it can be referenced from your Visualforce page. That is why the error message says the property is unknown - it doesn't exist, yet.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> pageToWordMap { get; private set; }
// the private keyword here prevents the value from being set via Visualforce, 
// it can only be set within testClass
```

To prevent issues with `null` values it's also a good idea to set pageToWordMap to an empty map in a constructor.

```
public testClass() {
    pageToWordMap = new Map<String, List<Object>>();
}
```

Comment: ok. and how would I use this to create a record table in VF page?

Comment: @SuelAhmed that's a good point, `apex:pageBlockTable` expects a List and not a Map. Outputting your map's values may be problematic since they're generic `Object`s. You may need a new, wrapper class to hold the values you're interested in (name, bvdid, and country code).

Comment: there was another way I created a wrapper class, Please refer to question

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311497/how-to-display-the-following-json-deserialized-to-vf-page

Again the question arises on how to use this to create a VF page

Comment: @SuelAhmed your other post has the same issue. The Visualforce page can only access properties from a class, so you will need to make `Data` a property by giving it a getter, and then you need to reference each field you want in your table by giving it a column. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm

Comment: I understand the problem now but if its possible can you give me a small example on how to do exactly what you said?